# how find new node selected in jtree?

Tags: java, listener, jtree

how find new node selected in jtree? or understand selected node changed?

Answer (score 2):

you can read on [TreeSelectionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html)